# Is there a way of comparing all the values within 2 entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm using EF4.3 so I'm referring to entities, however it could apply to any class containing properties.

I'm trying to figure out if its possible to compare 2 entities. Each entity has properties that are assigned values for clarity let say the entity is 'Customer'.

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
}
```

The customer visits my website and types in some details 'TypedCustomer'. I check this against the database and if some of the data matches, I return a record from the database 'StoredCustomer'.

So at this point I've identified that its the same customer returning but I wan't to valid the rest of the data. I could check each property one by one, but there are a fair few to check. Is it possible to make this comparison at a higher level which takes into account the current values of each?

```
if(TypedCustomer == StoredCustomer)
{
    .... do something
}
```

Comment: Why would you not reload the data? If it's still in memory can it be that someone or something else modified it? What would make the data "valid" and what would invalidate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're storing these things in the database, it is logical to assume you'd also have a primary key called something like `Id`.

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Then all you do is:

```
if(TypedCustomer.Id == StoredCustomer.Id)
{
}
```

UPDATE:

In my project, I have a comparer for these circumstances:

```
public sealed class POCOComparer<TPOCO> : IEqualityComparer<TPOCO> where TPOCO : class
{
    public bool Equals(TPOCO poco1, TPOCO poco2)
    {
        if (poco1 != null && poco2 != null)
        {
            bool areSame = true;
            foreach(var property in typeof(TPOCO).GetPublicProperties())
                {
                    object v1 = property.GetValue(poco1, null);
                    object v2 = property.GetValue(poco2, null);
                    if (!object.Equals(v1, v2))
                    {
                        areSame = false;
                        break;
                    }
                });
            return areSame;
        }
        return poco1 == poco2;
    }   // eo Equals

    public int GetHashCode(TPOCO poco)
    {
        int hash = 0;
        foreach(var property in typeof(TPOCO).GetPublicProperties())
        {
            object val = property.GetValue(poco, null);
            hash += (val == null ? 0 : val.GetHashCode());
        });
        return hash;
    }   // eo GetHashCode
}   // eo class POCOComparer
```

Uses an extension method:

```
public static partial class TypeExtensionMethods
{
    public static PropertyInfo[] GetPublicProperties(this Type self)
    {
        self.ThrowIfDefault("self");
        return self.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where((property) => property.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0 && property.CanRead && property.CanWrite).ToArray();
    }   // eo GetPublicProperties


}   // eo class TypeExtensionMethods
```

Comment: Thats not what I want. The customer may be the same, but for instance they may have updated their mobile number.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's much of a purpose to checking the entire object in this scenario - they'd have to type every property in perfectly exactly as they did before, and a simple "do they match" doesn't really tell you a lot. But assuming that's what you want, I can see a few ways of doing this:

1) Just bite the bullet and compare each field. You can do this by overriding the `bool Equals` method, or `IEquatable<T>.Equals`, or just with a custom method.

2) Reflection, looping through the properties - simple if your properties are simple data fields, but more complex if you've got complex types to worry about.

```
foreach (var prop in typeof(Customer).GetProperties()) {
    // needs better property and value validation
    bool propertyMatches = prop.GetValue(cust1, null)
        .Equals(prop.GetValue(cust2, null));
}
```

3) Serialization - serialize both objects to XML or JSON, and compare the strings.

```
// JSON.NET
string s1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cust1);
string s2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cust2);
bool match = s1 == s2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most simple seems to use reflexion : get the properties and/or fields you want to compare, and loop through them to compare your two objects.
This will be done with getType(Customer).getProperties and getType(Customer).getFields, then using getValue on each field/property and comparing.
You might want to add custom informations to your fields/properties to define the ones that needs 
comparing. This could be done by defining a AttributeUsageAttribute, that would inherit from FlagsAttribute for instance. You'll then have to retrieve and handle those attributes in your isEqualTo method.